# Group data and create a new index whit it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this data in my index

```
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "carlos",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "license",
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "carlos",
    "page": 2
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "word": "testament",
    "page": 2
  }
```

but now i need to have a new index with the next structure

```
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "page": 1,
    "words": [
      {
        "word": "carlos"
      },
      {
        "word": "license"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "filekey": "book1",
    "page": 2,
    "words": [
      {
        "word": "carlos"
      },
      {
        "word": "testament"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Grouping words by book page

I already had a lookat [reindex](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) and [aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html)

But still not sure how to achieve this. Also i think i need to map words as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) cause i will need to filter elements inside the **words** array, so i don't get the full array, as it could contain hundreds of words and i need only the ones that matches

#### Edit:

**The problem:**

In the project we are currently searching for words in files, the text is scattered in words because each word have the "topography" of the word in the page, its coordinates, so we can visually highlight the specific text the person is looking for.
Now, we are running a basic query so we can filter the words upon a phrase the user is looking for in a page, and then we collapse the results per page so we don't get duplicated pages, but this is messing the score given by ES as it is searching for words individually and what the user need is to get the best match in the whole page and not per word. I couldn't be able to came up whit a query that groups the words and then filters upon the grouped words with my current structure, and if i would be able to came up with a correct query then it could be bad in performance as we have 800 gb of words stored in the ES index.
But the query would be more natural if i change the structure of the index where words are grouped by page

For context, this is the query i'm currently running

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
      { 
        match: {
          word: "testament salomon"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
collapse: {
    field: "Page",
    inner_hits: {
      name: "pages",
      collapse: {
        field: "filekey.keyword"
      },
      _source: ["Word", "Page"],
      size: 0
    }
}
```

this is the query i would run with the new structure

```
"query": {
    "match": {
      "words.word": {
        "query": "testament salomon"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm curious about your use case, as usually people strive for denormalizing their date when storing them into Elasticsearch (i.e. the first example you give), but you go the other way around and try to nest your data into the same documents. Can you explain a bit more how you'll want to query your data and give a few example of the queries that you were not able to achieve with your initial mapping?

Comment: @Val thanks for your interest man!
I made an edit to the question i hope it explains clearly the use case and why i need to change my structure

Comment: Thank you, although running nested queries over 800 GB of nested documents might not perform extremely well... I have seen use cases like yours in the past, let me recollect how that went.